# How to check if Fortran array contains value?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, fortran, where-clause, fortran90

I've seen this asked for other languages, but having just found out how nicely Fortran can handle arrays, I thought there might be an easy way to do this without loops.

Currently I'm searching over a 3D array looking at 'nearest neighbours' to see if they contain the letter 'n', and whenever it finds this value, I want it to perform some clusterLabel assignment (which isn't relevant for this question)

I wanted to use `if(lastNeighArray.eq."n") then...<rest of code>`
but for obvious reasons it doesn't like checking an array against a value. Neither does it like me using `lastNeighArray(:)`, even though I'd like it to check each of the elements one at a time. `where(lastNeighArray.eq."n")` doesn't work as I have a case statement inside the where loop and I get the error `WHERE statements and constructs must not be nested.`

So I'm a little stuck. What I really want is something like `when(lastNeighArray.eq."n")` but that doesn't exist.

I've also looked at `any` and `forall` but they don't seem like the right choice.

Comment: It's strange that you looked at ANY but didn't like it.

Comment: @Svetlana I don't think at the time I considered it fully. With two year experience I don't think I would have dismissed it so easily.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

ANY should actually be the right choice

```
if ( ANY( lastNeighArray=="n" ) ) then
```

there is also ALL if you wanted the whole array to contain that value.