# How to check every single element of my array (in a loop)?

Tags: arrays, loops, fortran

I am programming in Fortran and if all single elements of my array are positive I want to execute statement 1, if they are partly positive execute statement 2 and if all are negative execute statement 3.

I know I will probably need a 'do' loop and a 'if' construct but could not figure out how to do it best.

Comment: What did you try so far? Have a look at minval and maxval.

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour] and see [ask]. How are you stuck? Did you encounter any errors? Which errors? Whit which exact code? You probably just need to use `ALL()`, see very similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340592/how-to-check-if-fortran-array-contains-value

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to use loop for a simple condition

```
 if (ALL(A>0)) then
    statement1
 else if (ALL(A<0)) then
    statement3
 else
    statement2
 end if
```

Explanation: `A>0` is an array of logical values based on evaluating the condition for each element of the original array `A`. Function `ALL()` then reduces this logical array and returns true if all elements are true and false otherwise.

You request a do loop in the title. If you really need to fix a particular error with that, you must show us the code from your efforts, your errors and all other important details.

Comment: but how can I ask if exactly/more/less elements then x (variable defined before in the program) are a logical statement?

Comment: There is another function, `COUNT()` if I understand you correctly. You can ask a new question if you think it is necessary, first search and if it hasn't been asked before, ask a new question.